# How to correctly display images on React frontend that are returned by Laravel as StreamedResponse objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel

The idea is as follows:

1. Images/documents are stored privately on the server
2. A logged-in user on frontend clicks a button which sends an axios request to backend to get an aggregated result of ModelA from TableA and it's associated attachment file list from TableB
3. For each ModelA, numerous requests are made to endpoint to fetch images which are returned as `\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse` via `Storage::download($request->file_name)`

This works in the sense that files are returned.

*Note - I tried attaching all files to response in step 2 but this didn't work, so added the extra step to get file list and get individual files after that based on the list. This might kill the webserver if the amount of requests becomes too high, so would appreciate any advise on a different approach.*

**The problem**
How to display the files in React and is this the right approach at all considering potential performance issues noted above?

I've tried the following:

1. Create an `octet-stream` url link with `FileReader` but these wouldn't display and had the same url despite `await` being used for the `reader.readAsDataURL(blob)` function:

```
const { email, name, message, files } = props
const [previews, setPreviews] = useState<string[]>([])
const { attachments } = useAttachment(files)

useEffect(() => {
    const p = previews

    files && attachments?.forEach(async filename => {
      const reader = new FileReader()
    
      reader.onloadend = () => {
        p.push(reader.result as string)
        setPreviews(p)
      }
      const blob = new Blob([filename])
      await reader.readAsDataURL(blob)
    })
  }, [files, attachments, previews])
```

2. Create src attributes with `URL.createObjectURL()` but these, although generated and unique, wouldn't display when used in an `<img />` tag:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const p = previews

    files && attachments?.forEach(filename => {
      const blob = new Blob([filename])
      const src = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
      p.push(src)
      setPreviews(p)
    })
  }, [files, attachments, previews])
```

Results example:

```
<img src="blob:http://127.0.0.1:8000/791f5efb-1b4e-4474-a4b6-d7b14b881c28" class="chakra-image css-0">
<img src="blob:http://127.0.0.1:8000/3d93449e-175d-49af-9a7e-61de3669817c" class="chakra-image css-0">
```

[image: As displayed in UI]

Here's the `useAttachment` hook:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { api } from '@utils/useAxios'

const useAttachment = (files: any[] | undefined) => {
  const [attachments, setAttachments] = useState<any[]>([])

  const handleRequest = async (data: FormData) => {
    await api().post('api/attachment', data).then(resp => {
      const attach = attachments
      attach.push(resp)
      setAttachments(attach)
    })
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    if (files) {
      files.forEach(async att => {
        const formData = new FormData()
        formData.append('file_name', att.file_name)
        await handleRequest(formData)
      })
    }
  }, [files, attachments])

  return { attachments }
}

export default useAttachment
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by sending the files in a single response but encoded with `base64encode(Storage::get('filename'))`. Then, on the frontend, it was as simple as:

````
const base64string = 'stringReturned'

<img> src={`data:image/png;base64,${base64string}`}</img>```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try `Storage::response()`. This is the same as `Storage::download()` just that it sets the `Content-Disposition` header to `inline` instead of `attachment`.
This tells the browser to display it instead of downloading it. [See MDN Docs Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition#as_a_response_header_for_the_main_body)
Then you can use it as the `src` for an `<img/>`.